# How to place object on top of ui?

Tags: unity, unity-ui

I'm trying to place a 3D object on top of a UI Image

But nothing works. Can anyone give an example of how to add a 3d model on top of a UI Image in a 2d game.

The strange thing is that I have all the objects closer to me in the Z- coordinate.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Another oddity is that Sprite objects ignore hierarchy. They are always above the UI Image and the only thing they react to is Additional Settings

[image]

Why does the hierarchy not work for me?
Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?
Where is the mistake?

Comment: As much as I know, unity shows UI elements in a canvas according to their index (child one, child two, etc.) so are you sure the elf is on top of the image? btw, why would you like to show a 3d model in a 2d game?

Comment: Because the sprite editor is shit. 
I have tried with psb. but unity clips it and creates a terrible mesh.
Auto Weights is terrible.
Manually adjusting each layer is too long.
And there are too many layers, so it takes a long time to load.
I tried to create one image, customize it and then change it use code 
But in the end, he just lost the grid of scales and bones.

Comment: Sorting by hierarchy works only for UI objects. 3D content like meshes will be sorted by depth from the camera, not position in the canvas hierarchy, so they should not be placed as a child of the canvas.